# Unmarshalling in jaxb for enum type

Tags: java, enums, jaxb

I am using Jaxb for marshalling & unmarshalling. from xml i want data unmarshalled to a java object having an enum attribute which is like the one shown below with the constructor, getter & setter for the enum field.

```
public enum MyEnum {
  P_E("p e")
  private String type;
}
```

I understand from other stackoverflow questions that jaxb does not require setters for setting the value. in xml if i give value as "P_E" it works well. is there a way to use "p e" and set the enum value in object?.  Also without using the setter, how does jaxb work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlEnumValue` annotation to change the XML representation.